# I'm getting only a subset of widgets when I download Orange 3.23.1

Tags: python, widgets

I recently downloaded Orange 3.23.1 and am getting only a subset of the baseline widgets when I run the app.  For example, I do not see the "Scatter Plot" widget in the Visualize group.  Instead, I get only the "Box Plot" and "Venn Diagram" widgets.

I had downloaded the previous version of Orange and had the same issue, so I uninstalled it and installed the newest version.  I'm running on a PC where I had also previously performed code development for Python 3.  I thought that might be the problem so I have uninstalled all Python dev environments (non-trivial and time consuming), but still no luck after another uninstall and install of Orange.  All insight/advice appreciated.